# Run UNIX command in PHP wamp

Tags: php, unix

I want to run UNIX command in my Wamp(PHP 5.6,Windows 10).

this is my command 
`exec('unoconv -e Quality=300 -f pdf "'C:\wamp64\www\mb_new\photos/service_pdfs/41963samplepptx__cwt.pptx'"', $arr)`;

this is working fine in my server.

Comment: It can't run ok on windows because you don't have unoconv on windows.

Answer (score 0):

In windows you can use unoconv with python. See the github example:
https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv

`C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4.4\program\python.exe unoconv -f pdf some-file.odt`